# If I have a fixed navbar, the text is under the navbar. How do I get the text under the navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

If I make a fixed navbar in Bootstrap and add some text, then is the text under the navbar. Like this: [image] How can I fix it?

Comment: Add some padding or margin to the container w/the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some padding to the body, like `body { padding-top: 70px; }`, see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top in Bootstraps documentation.